# Displaying an alternative result when derrived table is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this sql code where I try to display an alternative value as a result whenever the table is empty or the the single column of the top row when it is not

```
select top 1 case when count(*)!=0 then derrivedTable.primarykey
else 0 end endCase
from
(   
    select top 1 m.primarykey
    from mytable m
    where 0=1
)derrivedTable
```

The problem is that when I run this, I get the error message "column 'derrivedTable.primarykey' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
But when I put 'derrivedTable.primarykey' in the group by clause, I just get an empty table.
Does anyone hve a solution?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select coalesce(max(m.primarykey), 0)
from mytable m;
```

An aggregation query with no `group by` *always* returns exactly one row.  If the table is empty (or all rows are filtered out), then the aggregation functions -- except for `COUNT()` -- return `NULL` -- which can be transformed to a value using `COALESCE()`.

Such a construct makes me worry.  If you are using this to set the primary key on an insert, then you should learn about `identity` columns or sequences.  The database will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below script-

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN derrivedTable.primarykey
    ELSE 0
END endCase
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 m.primarykey
    FROM mytable m
    WHERE 0 = 1
) derrivedTable
derrivedTable.primarykey;
```